# require php file without the html content

Tags: php, html

I want to to require only the (functions, classes, variables) from another PHP file but that file have some html content which I don't want.

I already tried `require, include, INCLUDE_ONCE, REQUIRE_ONCE` but none worked

Comment: I would go with best practices, and don't include the HTML directly in the PHP file in the first place. Or if you absolutely must, move all of the functions/classes/variables into a single PHP file and call it `functions.php` and just include that where it is needed.

Comment: Create a file with the functions and without the HTML. Then include that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments suggested, the best way is to reorganize the code so you don't mix functions and HTML in the include file.

But if you really need to do this, you can do it with the [output buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) functions.

```
ob_start();
require 'filename.php';
ob_end_clean();
```